# Trying to Optimise jQuery function used in SharePoint Page

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2007

I'm attempting to optimise the jQuery code below, it iterates through all the TD tags on the page searching for any that has "eventClassXXXXXX" as its class attribute (where "XXXX" could be numeric or alphabetic).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("class", this.className.replace(/eventClass/gi, 'eventClass '));
    });
});
```

so it would change

```
"<TD class='eventClass12345678'>"
```

to

```
"<TD class='eventClass'>
```

The problem is it takes ages to run on a sharepoint page (right-click on a sharepoint page and click view source to see why). The reason I have to do this is becauyse there is a third party webpart on the page that I'm attempting to restyle (wasn't supplied as open-source)

Let me know if you have any ideas on optimizing this or another way round. Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would be faster:

```
$('td[class^=eventClass]').attr('class','eventClass');
```

If there's some sort of container element available (perhaps the table), this would be much better:

```
$('#container').find('td[class^=eventClass]').attr('class','eventClass');
```

Comment: thanks for responding, i'll test and let you know if it works

Comment: seems slightly quicker, will update if I find any other alternatives... thanks Ken